# Web3.py TypeError: Transaction had invalid fields: {'value': Decimal

Tags: python, function, max, ethereum, web3py

Wondering if anyone knows how I can send the max amount of ether or my entire eth balance through web3.py? here the chunk of code that ive been kind of working with. In 'value' I can only send an specific amount of ether and have no clue how to get it to find out the max amount of ether it can send.

```
balance_sender = web3.from_wei(web3.eth.get_balance(sender_address), 'ether')
balance_recipient = web3.from_wei(web3.eth.get_balance(recipient_address), 'ether')

print(f'The balance of {sender_address} is: {balance_sender} ETH')
print(f'The balance of {recipient_address} is: {balance_recipient} ETH')

# Get and determine gas parameters
latest_block = web3.eth.get_block("latest")
base_fee_per_gas = latest_block.baseFeePerGas   # Base fee in the latest block (in wei)
max_priority_fee_per_gas = web3.to_wei(1, 'gwei') # Priority fee to include the transaction in the block
max_fee_per_gas = (5 * base_fee_per_gas) + max_priority_fee_per_gas # Maximum amount you’re willing to pay

# Define the transaction parameters
transaction_params = {
    'from': sender_address,
    'to': recipient_address,
    'value': web3.to_wei(0.002, 'ether'),  # Transaction value (0.1 Ether in this example)
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address),
    'gas': 21000,  # Gas limit for the transaction
    'maxFeePerGas': max_fee_per_gas, # Maximum amount you’re willing to pay
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': max_priority_fee_per_gas, # Priority fee to include the transaction in the block
    'chainId': 11155111  # ChainId of Sepolia Testnet
}

# Sign the transaction
transaction = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction_params, private_key)

# Send the transaction
transaction_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(transaction.rawTransaction)

# Wait for the transaction to be mined
transaction_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(transaction_hash)
```

I've tried creating a function that subtracts gas from balance_sender but it simply returned

> TypeError: Transaction had invalid fields: {'value': Decimal('0.011652999998614')}'

Comment: Could you clarify which line of the code above raise the TypeError exception? Was it `transaction = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(...)`?

Comment: raise TypeError("Transaction had invalid fields: %r" % invalid)
TypeError: Transaction had invalid fields: {'value': Decimal('0.011652999998614')}

(the current code I have should work but I'm trying to get it to send entire account balance and right now it has to be manually set)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`value`: int(web3.to_wei(0.002, 'ether'))

Comment: Well with int it's still sending a set amount of ether, I'm trying to make it send the entire eth balance and it is sending a locked amount, so if the eth balance were to change and I tried running this code, I would have to manually reenter the 'value'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [estimate_gas](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.estimate_gas) to estimated the gas required for the transaction. To get the estimated maximum sendable value `send_value`, you can then minus the sender wei balance with the estimated gas times either `max_fee_per_gas` or `base_fee_per_gas`

```
send_value = balance_sender_wei - estimated_gas * max_fee_per_gas
```

```
balance_sender_wei = web3.eth.get_balance(sender_address)
balance_sender = web3.from_wei(balance_sender_wei, 'ether')
balance_recipient = web3.from_wei(web3.eth.get_balance(recipient_address), 'ether')

print(f'The balance of {sender_address} is: {balance_sender} ETH')
print(f'The balance of {recipient_address} is: {balance_recipient} ETH')

# Get and determine gas parameters
latest_block = web3.eth.get_block("latest")
base_fee_per_gas = latest_block.baseFeePerGas   # Base fee in the latest block (in wei)
max_priority_fee_per_gas = web3.to_wei(1, 'gwei') # Priority fee to include the transaction in the block
max_fee_per_gas = (5 * base_fee_per_gas) + max_priority_fee_per_gas # Maximum amount you’re willing to pay


tx = {
    'from': sender_address,
    'to': recipient_address,
    'value': int(balance_sender),
}

estimated_gas = web3.eth.estimate_gas(tx)
send_value = balance_sender_wei - estimated_gas * max_fee_per_gas

# Define the transaction parameters
transaction_params = {
    'from': sender_address,
    'to': recipient_address,
    'value': int(send_value)
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address),
    'gas': estimated_gas,  # Gas limit for the transaction
    'maxFeePerGas': max_fee_per_gas, # Maximum amount you’re willing to pay
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': max_priority_fee_per_gas, # Priority fee to include the transaction in the block
    'chainId': 11155111  # ChainId of Sepolia Testnet
}
```